# 8 questions about facebook registration plug-in

Tags: facebook, plugins, registration

I am working in c#.net 4.0 and trying to impliment facebook registration plug-in as documented here  [developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/).
in the way of implimentation facing the following issues, can someone please provide the answers of following question.

1. All the fields are required, how to add optional fields?
2. When I add more than 3 items in a drop down list it start to giving error, whereas if more items are required a project then?
3. Max 16 fields can be added in FB registration form, if some more fields are needed then what to do?
4. No way to add radio button?
5. How to add check for terms & conditions?
6. How to add client side and server side async validation both at a time?
7. How to validate more than one fields by using async validation, like (email, username, coupon)?
8. How to add default text/value in a textbox.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your reputation is `8` and you have `8` questions, what a co-incidence... :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to use Facebook Connect API s which are outdated and will be out of use soon. Instead , I suggest you to use Facebook Graph API.

Which platform are you working with ? Can you mention it please .. If you are using .NET , then you can get the help here [Facebook Sdk Helper](http://facebooksdk.blogspot.com)

Comment: Thanks Balaji for your response, I am working in c#.net 4.0 and trying to impliment facebook registration plug-in as documented here  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/. Morever all the questions I stated above are not related to a specific platform or SDK